# How to define recursive GraphQL type programmatically?

Tags: javascript, graphql

Let's say, for example, I want to define a typical forum message type using GraphQL JavaScript interface:

```js
import {
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLObjectType,
} from 'graphql';

const MessageType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Message',
  fields: {
    text: { type: GraphQLString },
    comments: new GraphQLList(MessageType),
  },
});
```

The JavaScript compiler (well, interpreter) would complain about this. It would say that `MessageType is undefined`.

We all know it is possible to define such a type using the GraphQL language:

```graphql
type Message {
    text: String
    comments: [Message]
}
```

How could you define such a type using GraphQL pure JavaScript interface?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the answer is simple.

You just need to pass a thunk (function without arguments) as the `field` field instead of passing plain JavaScript object.

The function would be executed only when the type would already be defined, so, it will work.

Resulting code looks like this:

```js
import {
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLObjectType,
} from 'graphql';

const MessageType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Message',
  fields: () => ({  // <-- Notice the function definition
    text: { type: GraphQLString },
    comments: new GraphQLList(MessageType),
  }),
});
```